# Why is my ng-repeated div not displaying as an inline-block?

Tags: css, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to ng-repeat through an array of skills and have them display as inline-blocks, but for some reason there are line breaks between each skill.

```
<div class="skillsWrapper" style="display: inline-block" ng-repeat="skill in hero.equipment.skills track by $index">
        <span class="profileSkill">{{skill}}<span ng-if="!$last">,</span></span>
    </div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.skillsWrapper
    display: inline-block; 
    text-align: center;


.profileSkill
    display: inline-block;
```

I would like the skills to display like `throwing, climbing, fighting` but they show up with line-breaks like

```
throwing,
climbing,
fighting
```

How can I fix this, and why isn't it working as is?

Comment: What's the styling that's right now on `.profileSkill`?

Comment: Please post your CSS. This is a CSS problem.

Comment: Inspect the element and see if any styles are overriding the inline-block attribute.